# How to desgin a json string with several objects in codeigniter?

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I have two tables, table `photos` with following data

photoid    photoname
1           1.png

2           2.png

3           x.png

4           w.png

... and more
and table `photocomment` with following database,

pcid  photoid  commentcontent

1      2        here some comments

... and more

I want to get the json string like this

```
{
    "status":"1",
    "fbmsg":"success",
    "photolist":[
    {
        "photoid":"1",
        "photoname":"1.png",
        "commentlist":[
         {
            "pcid":"1",
            "commentcontent":"here some comments"
          },
          ... more results  
         ]
       },
        .... more results
     ]
    }
```

in CI controller, i wrote

```
  $this->load->model('bbs_model');
  $query = $this->bbs_model->listphotos();
  if ($query) {
    echo json_encode(array(
      'status' => 1,
      'fbmsg' => 'success',
      'typelist' => $query
    ));
    exit();
  }
```

and in CI model, i wrote

```
  function listphotos()
  {
    $query = $this->db->query("select * from photos order by photoid asc");
    return $query->result_array();
   }
```

how can i modify the controller and model to create the json string above? thanks.

Comment: Produce the array as you wanted and `json_encode` it.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam thank you, how can i get the  `commentlist ` in model and controller?